# Regular expression to match Date

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate following date format through **regExp**, but still i didn't get ant working solution-

```
ex.-

OCT-12-2011
FEB-06-1995
```

how can i do it using regexp.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... not sure how strictly you want to do this.

```
var months = [
        'JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN','JUL','AUG','SEP','OCT','NOV','DEC'
    ],
    regValidate = RegExp('^(?:' + months.join('|') + ')-[0-3][0-9]-\\d{4}$');

alert(regValidate.test('OCT-12-2011'));
```

Answer (score 4):

[Date JS](http://www.datejs.com/) is the first hit on Google.

[image: Poverful yet simple!]

> Comprehensive, yet simple, stealthy and fast. Datejs has passed all trials and is ready to strike. Datejs doesn’t just parse strings, it slices them cleanly in two.

Sample code from their site:

```
Date.parse('today');
Date.parse('t + 5 d'); // today + 5 days
Date.parse('next thursday');
Date.parse('February 20th 1973');
Date.parse('Thu, 1 July 2004 22:30:00');
```

The only downside is that it modifies the prototype of build-in `Date` object. Although it's considered a discouraged practice I doubt that these particular additions will affect you application. There are still plenty of sites using [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) without any problems.

---

*EDIT*: ragarding parsing Date values via RegExps.
Be very careful especially considering different date.toString() implementation in different browsers. Here's what `new Date().toString()` gave me:

- IE9: `"Mon Jul 11 14:50:45 UTC+0300 2011"`
- FF5: `"Mon Jul 11 2011 14:51:08 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)"`

If you get those strings from the server and you feel that adding a library just for dates is an overhead you'll be fine with regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to validate it very strictly using a regex. Check the format, using something like this:

```
[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}
```

Then, check each part to see whether that part is valid.

Comment: +1, regex is definitely not the way to validate dates, you can try some of the answers, but you validate date, not the string representation of it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on you requirements, the following could do:

```
^[A-Z]{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$
```

Or more elaborate:

```
^(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-[12]\d{3}$
```

Or anything in between :) (You may even elaborate further on the year part.)

Comment: Months usually have dates ranging from 01 to 31, not just up to 12!

Comment: @Kerrek SB No, I just noticed :) Corrected, but thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with a single regexp, you could use something like:

```
/^(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)-([012]\d|3[01])-[12]\d{3}$/
```

This will not match a date before JAN-01-1000 or after DEC-31-2999.

Note: do not forget to check for invalid february dates like FEB-30-2011